# Vector iterator

Tags: c++

I have a vector like this

```
std::vector<Sprite*> mDrawings;
std::vector<Sprite*>::iterator it = mDrawings.begin();
```

This gives an error

```
Error: no suitable user-defined conversion from std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<Sprite *, std::allocator<Sprite *>>> to std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<Sprite *, std::allocator<Sprite *>>> exists
```

But if i do the following

```
typedef std::vector<Sprite*> list;
list mDrawings;
list::iterator it = mDrawings.begin();
```

Then it works ???.

UPDATE: 
Im sorry it seems like the error was generated because of errors not related to the current code. I just saw the IDE underline with red and i thought that was the reason my application would not compile.

Comment: Can you show us the entire error? I don't really see a problem here...

Comment: Just a hint: if your compiler supports TR1, you can use `auto it = mDrawings.begin();` instead of `std::vector<Sprite*>::iterator it = mDrawings.begin();`

Comment: Post a complete, minimal testcase on ideone.com that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Here is a stripped down code example: http://ideone.com/Cw8XZ

Comment: @madslee: And here I've fixed the problems in that for you: http://ideone.com/2tsAY - It does not demonstrate the question.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is it particularly old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you pasted the wrong code - I think perhaps you did `std::vector<Sprite>::iterator it = mDrawings.begin();` without the `*`

EDIT: In response to updated question:

Always look at the *first* compiler error - Your code, as posted on ideone, lacks an `#include` which makes `Sprite` visible.

Comment: You are absolutely right, im sorry as i describe in my update im used to just blindly thrust that if the IDE mark a line in red, i can assume thats the problem :) (The problem wasnt that i hadnt included the Sprite.h, that was just a typo in the pastebin dump)

Answer (score 3):

Your pasted code doesn't actually show the error. However, here's another shot in the dark:

Is it possible that in your original case, `mDrawings` is a member variable of some class (just guessign from the `m` prefix) and that your real code is in a const method? If so, you'd be trying to assing a `const_iterator` (since that's what calling `begin()` on a const vector will yield) to an `iterator`, which isn't possible.

Try using

```
std::vector<Sprite *>::const_iterator it = mDrawings.begin();
```

does that work better?

Comment: If that was the case the typedef wouldn't help though.

Comment: @Erik: Depends on where he did the typedef (and the object instantiation); maybe he did it within the const method (in which case it'd work, `mDrawings` would shadow the member variable).

Comment: Hi Frerich i think you are guessing right, im quite new to c++ but please have a look at http://ideone.com/Cw8XZ, and changing to const_iterator did not help :)

Comment: @madsleejensen: The code posted on ideone doesn't have the problem you describe.